# Замена тега на bb код с помощью preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Прошу помочь с составлением регулярного выражения для замены ссылки BB кодом. Имеется ссылка вида `<a href="какой-то-урл" class="какой-то-класс" onclick="какая-то-функция" rel="nofollow">`.
Эту ссылку нужно заменить на `[img]какой-то-урл[/img]`
Никак не удается написать регулярку для preg_replace, чтобы не цеплялись прочие ссылки в тексте с другими последовательностями атрибутов.

Comment: Подразумеваете замену только тегов <a>, ссылающихся на картинки? Что планируете делать с содержимым тегов?

Comment: Да, менять нужно только теги <a>, которые ссылаются на картинки. Интересует только их адрес, помещенный в [img][/img], содержимое и другие атрибуты нужно просто выбрасывать. При этом в тексте множество различных ссылок, но их конструкции отличны от приведенной и трогать их нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код, который покроет 90-95% входных данных.

```
<?php

$t = 'some text <a href="какой-то-урл" class="какой-то-класс" onclick="какая-то-функция" rel="nofollow">';
$exp = '/<a\s+href="([^>"]+)"\s+class="[^"]+"\s+onclick="[^"]+"\s+rel="nofollow">/';
$rep = '[img]\1[/img]';
echo preg_replace($exp, $rep, $t);
```

поправил код. Если "какой-то класс"/"какая-то-функция" - строго известный - подставляйте правильное.

Comment: А куда денутся закрывающие теги?

Comment: останутся. В Вашем примере их нет. Если хотите лучше код - приводите правильные входные данные.

Comment: Дело в том, что такой код действительно покрывает почти все ссылки в тексте, но моя задача заключается в замене только тех ссылок, которые соответствуют приведенной конструкции

Comment: А атрибуты будут только в указанном порядке? Могут ли быть ещё какие то атрибуты?

Comment: @KoVadim У меня к качеству кода совершенно нет претензий. Я тут мимо проходил :) Просто подумалось, раз есть открывающий тег, должен быть и закрывающий

Comment: Количество и порядок следования атрибутов строго как в примере. Если атрибуты следуют в другом порядке или их больше(меньше), то такую ссылку цеплять нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо! Новый вариант идеально подошел